# Sign of the wave function in orbital representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, conventions

I have some fog in my head and a rather simple question for you:

When the sign of the wave function is representated on orbitals, what is this sign? I mean is it the sign of the **real part** of the wave function only? Or is it the sign of the complex wave function?

Thanks if you have any clue/explanation/links about this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking of illustrations like this?

[image: Orbital]

If so, the sign just means that (in this case) $\Psi(-x) = -\Psi(x)$. There is no absolute sense in which one half of the orbital is negative and the other positive.

Comment: yes exactly, i am thinking of this kind of illustration. I agree on the point there is no absolute meaning to the sign, but still signs are opposite. but I am wondering where is this opposition? Just in the real part? or in the total sign of the wavefunction? Can this sign opposition can originate from the imaginary part as well?

Comment: If $\Psi(x)$ is $a + ib$ then $\Psi(-x) = -1*\Psi(x) = -1(a + ib) = -a - ib$.

Comment: So, in that representation, the wave function from one side to another has opposite sign for both imaginary and real part. pretty interesting. I have my answer, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @John Rennie Is there a need to involve complex conjugation (as in the definition of even and odd complex functions)?